# Android get text from editText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton(){

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                input1 = editTextView1.getText().toString();
                input2 = editTextView2.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Answer (score 1):

First initialize the `editText` just like you initialize the `Button` and `TextView` then you are able to get the text from `editText`

Answer (score 0):

you must have initialize.

(EditText, input1 and input2).

in Activity :

```
EditText editTextView1;
EditText editTextView2;
String input1;
String input2;
```

in onCreate :

```
editTextView1 = (EditText) findViewById(yourEditText1_Id);
editTextView2 = (EditText) findViewById(yourEditText2_Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little code that might help point you in the right direction. Post your code and I'll make the code fit your needs.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
TextView  textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextView1);
EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextView2);
}


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
 switch (view.getId()) {
 case R.id.button:
        input1 = editText1.getText().toString();
        input2 = editText2.getText().toString();
 break;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just going to make some of the answers above a bit clearer. An `Activity` is like a `Class` in a regular Java program. That means that it has fields (variables) and methods (functions). You can't access a field from within a method unless you declare in within the body of the class, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    EditText input1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // normal onCreate stuff
        input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1); 
        // this should be the id in your layout.xml file
    }
    public String getText(){
        String s = input1.getText().toString().trim();
        return s;
    }
}
```

Note the use of the `trim()` method, which will remove any extra whitespace the user may have added at the end of their input.